# On primality of the numbers of the form $10^{2k} - 10^{(k+1)} -1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Has anyone seen proof that numbers of the form $10^{2k} - 10^{k+1} - 1 \space \forall k \ge 2$ are prime?

Comment: They aren't so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false. For $k=5$ we have $10^{2k}-10^{k+1}-1=5002001\cdot 1999$.

Comment: gah silly me! :-) thanks

Comment: @AhmedMasud In case you're interested, $k=6,8,9,10$ also aren't prime.

Comment: it's been one of those mornings

Answer (score 4):

As Matt Samuel noted, they are not all prime. It's also unknown whether infinitely many of them are prime. In fact, it's not known whether 
there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^2 - 10 x - 1$: this is a special case of Bunyakovsky's conjecture.

BTW, after $k=7$ the next that are prime are $k=44, 75, 119$.  No more under $300$.

Comment: what got me interested in this was that I'd noted $[{10^{2k}-10^{k+1}-1}]^{-1}$ produces Fibonacci series (obviously) and thought it was an interesting expression to explore